# How to perform unit test in controller?

Tags: scala, specs2, playframework-2.4

Let say, i have controller like the following:

```
class JenisKejahatanControl @Inject()(service: JenisKejahatanService, val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  def add = Action.async { implicit request =>
    lazy val incoming = JenisKejahatan.formJenisK.bindFromRequest()

    incoming.fold( error => {
      lazy val response = ErrorResponse(BAD_REQUEST, messagesApi("request.error"))
      Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.toJson(response)))
    }, { newJenisK =>
      lazy val future = service.addJenisK(newJenisK)
      future.flatMap {
        case Some(jenis) => Future.successful(Created(Json.toJson(SuccessResponse(jenis))))
        case None => Future.successful(BadRequest(Json.toJson(ErrorResponse(NOT_FOUND, messagesApi("add.jenis.kejahatan.fail")))))
      }
    })
  }
}
```

and the i want to test my def add using specs2, how to do it?

Comment: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithSpecs2#Unit-Testing-Controllers

Comment: i have read it, but still i don't understand how to apply it for my controller

Comment: What do you want to test? the logic of this method? the route? can you describe in words what you want to test? (There are many tests that can be written here)

Comment: sorry, i beginner at unit test.
i want to test route of add method, for example:
when i run route /api/add/jenis, it will add data jenis kejahatan into database without have to use postman?
sorry if my english so bad

Answer (score 2):

Since your controller has injected components the bit I assume that one bit you're missing is how to obtain an instance of it in your spec with the various dependencies satisfied. For this you can use the [`GuiceApplicationBuilder`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder) to obtain a Play application instance, and then use its `injector` to get an instance of your controller without having to construct it manually (more dependency injection docs [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection) and specifically about testing with Guice [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice).)

If you can construct your controller manually, as in the example, that's great and makes things simpler, but controllers tend to have non-trivial dependencies which you will most likely want to mock using the `overrides` method on the `GuiceApplicationBuilder`.

With an instance of your controller constructed, it's then really simple to "apply" a mock (fake) request to your action methods and determine that they give the status and body you expect. Here's an example:

```
import controllers.{SuccessResponse, JenisKejahatanControl}
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import play.api.inject.bind
import play.api.mvc.Result
import play.api.test.{FakeRequest, PlaySpecification}

import scala.concurrent.Future

class JenisKejahatanControlSpec extends PlaySpecification {

  "JenisKejahatanControl#add" should {
    "be valid" in {

      // Build an instance of a Play application using the
      // default environment and configuration, and use it
      // to obtain an instance of your controller with the
      // various components injected.
      val jenisController = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
        .overrides(  // Mock the data service
          bind[JenisKejahatanService]
           .toInstance(new MockJenisKejahatanService))
        .build()
        .injector
        .instanceOf[JenisKejahatanControl]

      // Create a "fake" request instance with the appropriate body data
      val request = FakeRequest().withFormUrlEncodedBody("name" -> "test")

      // Apply the request to your action to obtain a response
      val eventualResult: Future[Result] = jenisController.add.apply(request)

      // Check the status of the response
      status(eventualResult) must_== CREATED

      // Ensure the content of the response is as-expected
      contentAsJson(eventualResult).validate[SuccessResponse].asOpt must beSome.which { r =>
        r.jenis.name must_== "test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks man, but i still don't understand how to use GuiceApplicationBuilder for component JenisKejahatanService and MessageApi?

Comment: @kurokoA2 since the JenisKejahatanService and MessagesApi are both _injected dependencies_ of the controller, the GuiceApplicationBuilder should take care of wiring them with the code I've posted. I can't go into more details without knowing more about your application then you have posted in the question (and its really a different question.) Be sure to read [testing with Guice](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice) in the docs.

Comment: @kurokoA2 I've expanded the example with the data service overridden with a test mock. You shouldn't need to worry about the MessagesApi - the application builder will use the default one.

Comment: when i try make build instance, i got error not found type MockJenisKejahatanService, how to define mockJenisKejahatanService?